# WSO2 API Manager - SSL-cert for host name in conflict with localhost calls

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

There is a previous, unanswered and now deleted/hidden, post which pretty much sums up my own case

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925061/wso2-am-ssl-cert-issued-for-host-name-in-conflict-with-localhost-calls-in-prod

Problem applies to WSO2 APIM 4.*

Basically, WSO2 APIM is configured to do localhost calls in MANY places.
When adding a trusted SSL certificate, wildcard or for host, localhost doesn't work.

This WSO2 page for IDENTITY server describes possible solutions:

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/change-the-hostname/

But adding SAN to cert isn't possible and adding internal_hostname setting is without effect in API Manager.

Actually changing localhost in 2000+ places in 200+ files just doesn't make sense.
There has to be another way?
Wasn't a problem in earlier versions of the product.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following 2 changes if your certificate doesn't has "localhost" as a SAN entry.

1. Modify the app.origin.host with the required custom hostname in settings.json files in portals

**Publisher path:**
repository/deployment/server/webapps/publisher/site/public/conf/settings.json

**Admin portal path:** repository/deployment/server/webapps/admin/site/public/conf/settings.json

**Devportal path:**   repository/deployment/server/webapps/devportal/site/public/theme/settings.json

2. Add following property with the required custom hostname in the deployment.toml file

```
 [server]
 internal_hostname = "abc.com"
```